# Why is Dapper emitting IL code in CreateTableConstructor?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, il

I'm looking at the excellent Dapper micro-orm, and in the [Dapper.Rainbow](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Rainbow) project, there is some code that creates a table ctor, using IL. I was hoping someone could explain to me what this code is doing - obviously it's dynamically emitting code to create a constructor (or is it code to call a constructor, or both), but what is the code that's being emitted actually creating, and why is this needed?

Here's the code

```
protected Action<TDatabase> CreateTableConstructor(Type tableType)
{
    var dm = new DynamicMethod("ConstructInstances", null, new Type[] { typeof(TDatabase) }, true);
    var il = dm.GetILGenerator();

    var setters = GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == tableType)
        .Select(p => Tuple.Create(
                p.GetSetMethod(true),
                p.PropertyType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TDatabase), typeof(string) }),
                p.Name,
                p.DeclaringType
         ));

    foreach (var setter in setters)
    {
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        // [db]

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, setter.Item3);
        // [db, likelyname]

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, setter.Item2);
        // [table]

        var table = il.DeclareLocal(setter.Item2.DeclaringType);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, table);
        // []

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        // [db]

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, setter.Item4);
        // [db cast to container]

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, table);
        // [db cast to container, table]

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, setter.Item1);
        // []
    }

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return (Action<TDatabase>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TDatabase>));
}
```

Comment: Though I don't contribute to the project it appears to be building a constructor in which it can set the values of the model directly from the database model. It's just generating boiler plate code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the edits. So what is the c# equivalent of this IL ctor code - and is it doing this to save me from having to add these ctors to all my model classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it takes all the properties of the current type (which is derived from `Database<T>`) that look something like:

```
public Table<SomeEntity> SomeTable { get; private set; }
```

And creates a delegate that executes code like the following for each such property:

```
var table = new Table<SomeEntity>(db, "SomeTable");
db.SomeTable = table;
```